# Unable to insert into django model with foreign key pointing to user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am pretty new to django and I am working on a job portal website. My users are recruiters and students. When a recruiter posts a job, i am able to retrieve all the values from the form but unable to insert in my Internship Model. Can you guys help please?

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Recruiter(models.Model):

     STATUS_CHOICES = (
     ('Pending', 'Pending'),
     ('Accepted', 'Accepted'),
)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     position = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
     user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

     def __str__(self):
          return self.user.username     

 

class Internship(models.Model):
 recruiter = models.ForeignKey(Recruiter, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
 internship_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 internship_desc = RichTextField()
 start_date = models.DateField()
 end_date = models.DateField()
 posted_date = models.DateField()

 def __str__(self):
      return self.internship_title
```

views.py

```
def post_internship(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request,"Please login first")
        return redirect('login')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        start_date = request.POST['start_date']
        end_date = request.POST['end_date']
        internship_title = request.POST['internship_title']
        internship_desc = request.POST['internship_desc']
    
        user = request.user
        recruiter = Recruiter.objects.get(user=user)
        try:
            Internship.objects.create(recruiter=recruiter, internship_title=internship_title, 
     internship_desc=internship_desc, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date,  
     posted_date=date.today())
        except:
            print('error')

       return render(request, 'post_internship.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think i understand the point of richtext field  in your intership model.

```
internship_desc = RichTextField()
```

i would probably use a

```
 models.TextField
```

Comment: I have used ckeditor. That is why. I was not sure if I could save it using textfield

Comment: Then i think may be the title is going beyond 100 or the date format coming from the forms doesnt go with the date format of model. I prefer creating the internship object from the admin panel with "add intership button".

Comment: the others have deleted their answer :/ I tried what they said, but not working

Comment: I can't do that because a recruiter posts an internship, not an admin

Comment: it was a fk prob. I solved it. Thanks tho :)

Comment: btw, how do I use the created instance as a fk to an insertion in another model? For instance, for the internship object that has been created.

Comment: you should retrieve the object in view and pass it to the instance attribute, check updating model instance with instance attribute

Comment: I asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67287527/inserting-many-foreign-keys-pertaining-to-the-same-model-in-django